# Data binding: View to view binding, without java code

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

In my layout I have a checkbox, which should toggle the enabled state of a different view. This means, the checked value of one view, should be bound to the enabled value of a different view.

To me this sounds like a perfect use case for the new data binding library, which should be a simple line in xml in my opinion, without having to use Java code. Something like `android:enabled="@{(@id/chk_enabled).isChecked()}"` I'm thinking. Sadly enough this isn't valid, and I can't find any information on how to do this correctly.

That's why I'm wondering, is this even possible?

Comment: @PN10: Your solution requires me to bind a variable called state to my UI, which requires java to do something purely UI related. That's something I wanted to avoid. The answer from szymon2013 is what I was looking for

Comment: yeah ...good to know you got solution ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/showMore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <EditText
                android:enabled="@{showMore.checked ?true:false}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, this worked.
You can even shorten it by dropping the true/false like this:

`android:enabled="@{showMore.checked}"`